# Cumulative sum conditional to interval

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate the conditional sum of a data frame column for a set of intervals `[n, +∞)` (i.e., `≥ n`) applied to another column. In the example data below the intervals are applied to column `a` and the values in column `b` are conditionally summed. For `[0, +∞)` all of column `a` values are `≥ 0` so `b_sum` is the sum of all values. For `[3, +∞)` only one record is `≥ 3` so `b_sum` is 500.

Input data

```
  a    b          
1.1  100          
2.3  150          
0.1   20          
0.5   80          
3.3  500          
1.6  200
1.1  180
```

Desired outcome

```
n  b_sum
0   1230
1   1130
2    650
3    500
4      0
```

I am sure this would be easy enough using a `for` loop; however; I would like to avoid this approach and use a vectorized base `R` or `dplyr` approach.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Pascal. I would try a `for` loop but I understand that is not the most efficient approach in `R`. The example I give is trivial. The actual input data can have greater than a million records. I can do a sum by interval in `dplyr` but only for intervals unique for each record. My example has intervals that overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `vapply`

```
 n <- trunc(min(df1$a)) : ceiling(max(df1$a))


 b_sum <- vapply(n, function(i) sum(df1$b[!is.na(cut(df1$a,
                     breaks=c(i, Inf)))]), 0)
 b_sum
#[1] 1230 1130  650  500    0
data.frame(n, b_sum)
```

We don't need `cut` also

```
vapply(n, function(i) sum(df1$b[df1$a>i]), 0)
#[1] 1230 1130  650  500    0
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun that works. I tried on my 200k record data and it is fast too.

Answer (score 5):

Vectorized solution

```
df <- df[order(df$a), ] # sort by "a" column
ind <- findInterval(0:4, df$a) + 1 
sum(df$b) - cumsum(c(0,  df$b))[ind]
#[1] 1230 1130  650  500    0
```

Answer (score 4):

Boolean math. Multiply the vector by logical condition which gets turned into 0/1

```
 sapply(0:4, function(n) { sum( (sub("\\..+$", "", inp$a) >= n )*inp$b ) } )
#[1] 1230 1130  650  500    0

data.frame( n=0:4, 
            b_sum= sapply(0:4, function(n) sum( sub("\\..+$", "", inp$a) >= n)*inp$b) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
data.frame(n = 0:4, b_sum = with(df, sum(b) - c(0, cumsum(tapply(b, floor(a), sum)))))
```